# How to imagepng() save in storage only

Tags: php

I use `imagepng()` in php. It works well, but it's saved in storage and shown in browser. How do I make it just save in storage and not show in the browser?

```
    <?php

 session_start();

 $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'delivery');

 $kode_transaksi = $_SESSION['kode_transaksi'];
 $id_transaksi = $_SESSION['idtransaksi'];

 $im = imagecreatefrompng('images/konfirmasi.png');
 $imgname = 'konfirmasi.png';
 $white = ImageColorAllocate($im,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF);
 $black = ImageColorAllocate($im,0x00,0x00,0x00);
 $text= 'Kode Transaksi: ' . $kode_transaksi;

 ImageString($im,5,30,320,$text,$black);
 Header('Content-Type: image/png');
 ImagePNG($im, 'images/' . $imgname);

 session_destroy();

 $query = "SELECT email FROM pelanggan " .
    "WHERE id_pelanggan = (SELECT id_pelanggan FROM transaksi, pengiriman ".
    "WHERE transaksi.id_transaksi = pengiriman.id_transaksi AND transaksi.id_transaksi = $id_transaksi)";

 $to = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
    or die('Error select email address');

 $subject = 'Kode Konfirmasi Pembelian';
 $msg = "";
 $from = 'admin@qrshop.web.id';

 mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $from);

 header('pengiriman.php');

?>
```

This is full code of my php page.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A quick look at the manual would give you `imagepng ($im,  $filename)`

Comment: I tried it, but it's still show in browser. But it is not the real image. It is the image logo. Like when your image fail to load. You know?

Comment: Then you must be doing something that's not covered by the code you have posted.

Comment: Why are you sending `Header('Content-Type: image/png');` to the browser if you don't want to display an image?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Header('Content-Type: image/png');`

It tells your browser it's about to display an image while in fact you don't send anything, hence the broken image because "empty" is not a valid PNG image data.

Also, what's `header('pengiriman.php');`? Missed `Location:`?

Comment: Thank you. It works well now. I Appreciate for the help.